# What does the phrase 'Putting the Spring in Springfield' mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context

I am reading the book about the Simpsons and I don't understand this line:

> 'Putting the Spring in Springfield.'

The line is the title of chapter from the book. I suppose the line 'put the spring' means breathing life or revival or something like that. Regarding the meaning of the word 'spring', it could mean grow out, put out, bubble up or occur. I am not sure whether I'm right or not, so that's why I'm here. Does it mean breathing life to Springfield? Can anyone please explain to me what does it mean?

Also I did some research on it, and I think this line may be related to the song "We put the spring in Springfield" from the Simpsons.

[Link](https://m.youtube.com/watch?feature=youtu.be&t=1m48s&v=Eyh4i4dUDeo) to the song on YouTube.

[Link](https://deadhomersociety.com/zombiesimpsons/) to the online book

Comment: Did you look up the word "spring"? Please include evidence of research.

Comment: Firstly, English is not my native language. Secondly, I suppose the line 'put the spring' means breathing life or revival or something like that. Regarding the meaning of the word 'spring', it means grow out, put out, bubble up or occur. Sorry if I'm wrong.

Comment: If you explain in your question why you are confused and what you think the sentence means, then it shows effort, and it will probably get more answers too. Edit your question and include your research, the same research which you showed just now. It's also better if you post the relevant link, so users can read the entire article and get a better idea of the context. Is it a pun, as Feltz suggests (plausible) or does it also mean something? His answer is more than acceptable b/c you didn't post the link to the article IN the question.

Comment: "Dead Homer Society" is also a play on words, it's supposed to  remind us of the Robin William's movie "Dead Poets Society" P.S retracted vote to close the question. PPS add the full sentence (putting the spring in Springfield")  in the title, it will attract more views/interest

Comment: Avoid asking what a text or utterance means. Interpretation requests (criticism, discussion, analysis, and divining the author’s intent) are out of scope and may be removed. This applies to all English texts and utterances, including (but not limited to) song lyrics, poetry, and legal documents. See: “[What topics can I ask about here? - Help Center](/help/on-topic)”.

Comment: @MetaEd great. I post comments, encourage the newcomer to add their research, and put in some effort, and they do!  Then you come along and close it. What's the point? Close Yoichi's [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/462430/what-does-all-senses-cocked-mean) as being POB as well.

Comment: I suppose, r/EnglishLearning from Reddit can help me. Thanks all of you, I am sorry, I didn't know, that I was breaking the rules here, from this forum.

Comment: You haven't broken any rules, you just come to a jaded website populated by jaded users (that's also me). Stick around. Oh, and some of the comments we exchanged have been deleted too.

Comment: It's all right. In fact, I didn't expect that someone would respond to my post.

Comment: I've asked on meta to reopen the question https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11690/jaded-user-meets-new-contributor-posting-a-lazy-question I don't know if it will be successful. Let's hope so.

Comment: That is very kind of you. As I said earlier it's all right, I can still get some help from other places. You don't need to worry, you've already helped me more than you know.

Comment: The question is reopened. Well done, the question is perfectly on topic, and it's a really good one, too.

Comment: Thank you. As explained to me by native speakers from Reddit, it's a reference to "putting a spring in your step" which means to make you more lively. But maybe this line has a multi-level definition, like many jokes from the early days of the Simpsons. Thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: Hello Replica Foxtrot, and welcome to EL&U!

Comment: And hello to you, too! I find this place really interesting and useful. Although at the initial stage I thought that my question wouldn't fit into the rules of this forum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you view the linked video, the song is a defense of Springfield's local whorehouse. "Spring" in this case seems to be used both in the sense of "provide an uplifting experience" (as in "put a spring in your step") and also as a mild sexual reference, referring to the "spring" outward of an erect penis. (There are some visual references in the video — for example, a jack-in-the-box popping out accompanied by the line "we put the [sound-effect 'boing'] ... in Springfield.")

Comment: That's the song, but what about the article? Is any sexual innuendo also implied?

Comment: @Mari-LouA According to the website, the book "attempts to explain...[h]ow The Simpsons became the unprecedentedly awesome show it was"; it seems that "spring" here is used in the sense of "adding excitement". No sexual innuendo, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I think so, too.

Comment: It is a "burlesque house" rather than a brothel

Answer (score 9):

This is a common play on words, often done ironically.

For example:

> He puts the fun in funeral.

Without more context, I can't tell whether there is actually something about springs that the writers are making a joke about, or whether they are just being absurd.

Comment: I am not sure if there's absurd or a joke, actually this line is the title of chapter, like 'Part I – Putting the Spring in Springfield.' https://deadhomersociety.com/zombiesimpsons/

Comment: This answer is the probably the most useful way to respond to the posted question. The family of jokey statements along the lines of "He puts the _dent_ in _president_" and "She puts the _bomb_ in _abomination_" and "It puts the _stink_ in _distinction_" is vast and (from a practical perspective) probably limitless. Any attempt to locate a freestanding expression or a deeper meaning in connection with the invented slogan "Putting the Spring in Springfield" is probably doomed to failure. Or in other words, it 's likely to put the _lose_ in _illusion_.

Comment: Putting a "spring in your step" is actually spot on. I wish it had come to me, but it didn't.

Comment: Also from the Simpsons, [We put the Fun in Fundamentalist Dogma](https://i.redd.it/mw5kr550vth01.png)

Comment: I like to say that our IT department likes to put the "no" in "innovation".

Comment: We put the antics in pedantics, or does that hit too close to home...