# What does “all senses cocked” mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I found an article, titled “The mystery of people who speaks dozen of languages” written by Judith Thurman in the latest New Yorker (September 3 issue) very intriguing.

She introduces a 27-year old Peruvian linguist, Miguel Rojas-Bersia, a doctorial candidate at the Max Planck Institute for Psycholinguistic, who has good command of 22 living languages including English, French, German,Italian, Spanish, Russian, Mandarin, Hakka Chines, Japanese, Korean, Serbian, Esperanto, and so on, 13 of which he speaks fluently and is versed to classic languages such as Latin, Ancient Greek, Biblical Hebrew. Thurman describes this young hyper polyglot as;

> “He looks like any other laid-back young tourist, except for the
>   intense focus – **all senses cocked** –with which he takes in a new
>   environment. Linguistics is a formidable discipline.

I have no idea about the phrase, “all senses cocked,” and I checked several English dictionaries at hand as well as online dictionaries without avail.

What does “all senses cocked” mean? Is it a common English phrase?

Comment: I do not recognize this as an idiom. There may be further insight in the dictionary under *cock* (verb): https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/cock_2

Comment: The OED says both the sense of _cock the head/hat_ and the sense of _cock the hammer/pistol_ come from the characteristic motion (and in the case of early firearms, the characteristic shape) of a cock's head. Roosters used to be more obvious and common as examples for metaphors than they are today.

Comment: @JohnLawler: You might want to leave that as an answer, and merge the relevant other information into your own answer as well.

Answer (score 35):

This probably comes from the phrase 'cocking the gun' which means to ready the gun to fire. 'Senses cocked' would then translate to very alert or charged senses.

Comment: I agree that it means all senses are alert (+1) It could also be a reference back to the idioms of cocking an ear or an eye.

Comment: Here is an example of where it was used: http://www.blogginboutbooks.com/2009/12/

Answer (score 21):

It's not unusual to *cock your head*, or sometimes to *cock your ears* to hear something better. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cock) (senses 3/4) says that this use is a synonym of *prick up* or *point*, so that only animals can genuinely  *cock their ears*, and birds frequently *cock their heads*, whether male or female. *Cocking all senses* is an extension of this - whether an exciting metaphor or a step too far from someone who doesn't know the derivation is a personal choice.

Comment: To me it doesn't suggest this sense of _cock_, but (as ndp2018 says) _cocking a gun_.

Comment: I agree, in this context I would associate this phrase with the idiom ["cock your/an ear"](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/cock-an-your-ear), meaning "listen carefully". In this case, the young linguist isn't just alert to sound, but alert to all sensory input.

Comment: Maybe, as they say, "A little column A, a little column B".  Rather poetic, really.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> The OED says both the sense of *cock the head/hat* and the sense of *cock the hammer/pistol* come from the characteristic motion (and in the case of early firearms, the characteristic shape) of a cock's head. Roosters used to be more obvious and common as examples for metaphors than they are today.